# How to correctly use verbs like read/look/browse to express the meaning " Every morning I take a quick look at the news on CNN”？

Tags: phrases

I don't know the native way to express the meaning I put on the title, hope some friend here can help me ~~

Comment: On TV or website?

Comment: Note that in 'take a look', the verb has become a noun.

Comment: On TV like Cbs channel : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a quick look you can go with

[Glance](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/glance)(Merriam-Webster Dictionary) to take a quick look at something.

[Skim](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/skim) (Merriam-Webster Dictionary) to read, study, or examine superficially and rapidly

[Scan](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/scan) (Cambridge Dictionary) to look through a text quickly in order to find a piece of information that you want or to get a general idea of what the text contains

Example sentences would be "Every morning I skim the news on CNN."

Other verbs such as "view" or "check" are also used commonly. It varies from person to person. There is no single preferred verb for this action.

Comment: Thank you so much Banuyayi ! Thanks for the comments and big help.  I will use skim in future. :)